# Automapper en WebAPI .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, automapper

supongo que será ya la hora y que estoy bastante ofuscado. Planteo el siguiente escenario:

Tengo una solución Ionic + C# .Net Core dividida en varios proyectos.

**MainProject** 
Donde inicializo en Startup.cs varios servicios, entre ellos AutoMapper.

**WebApiProject**
De momento con un único método que lo único que hace es llamar a un servicio de...

**ServiceProject**
Trae datos del contexto, contiene los DTO y a través de AutoMapper realizar la correspondiente proyección de las entidades al DTO correspondiente.

Mi duda es la siguiente. ¿Estoy obligado a instalar también AutoMapper en WebApiProject? El Servicio necesita tanto el contexto como un DI de IMapper. ¿Hay alguna alternativa a tener que meter AutoMapper también a WebApi sólo para tener que pasar una referencia de IMapper?

Gracias

Comment: entiendo que `WebApiProject ` es un webapi en asp.met core, y `ServiceProject` es un class library, ahora que tipo de proyecto es `MainProject ` ?

Comment: no entendi la segunda pregunta, o quizas en mi respuesta ya la contenste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la idea es convertir entidades en el webapi, por ejemplo las que persistes con `entity framework` y definen tu dominio contra las que representan las `dto` (Data Transfer Object) que devolveras como respuesta en los actio, entonces si vas a tener que definir `automapper` en el proyecto `WebApiProject`

[How to get started with AutoMapper and ASP.NET Core 2](https://medium.com/ps-its-huuti/how-to-get-started-with-automapper-and-asp-net-core-2-ecac60ef523f)

como veras existe una extension para asp.net core

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para asi poder usar `AddAutoMapper()` al configurar el service

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddAutoMapper();
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Comment: Leandro como se configura para un proyecto Web API con .Net Framework?